# If there are two registrations for same component with different bound components, they should receive different instances?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I'm trying to understand how works bound lifestyle in Castle.Windsor and I think I don't get it yet :)

So in test below, I'm testing following assumptions:
1) if component is bound to something, it should receive same instance of something in whole dependency hierarchy, that is written in documentation, and is understandable and looks like it works.

2) if component has several registrations and first registration is bound, for bound instances it should work as in 1), for other instances it should produce instances as described in not bound registration. That is not mentioned in documentation, but look logical too me.

3) syntax allows to chain life styles, so in general under single name I should be able to register component with several bound components. It is not in test below, but that was in initial version and didn't worked as I thought.

4) **(actual question)** if there are two registrations for same component with different bound components, they should receive different instances? There I see two problems with this configuration:

a) somehow Windsor does not resolve all dependencies (`bound2.DataContext` is null)
b) `bound.DataContext` is equal to `bound2.Service.DataContext` which I think is not right (intuitive).

```
[TestFixture]
public class IocTests
{      
    [Test]
    public void BoundRegistrationsTest()
    {
        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.Register(
            Component.For<IDataContext>()
                 .ImplementedBy<DataContext>()
                 .LifestyleBoundTo<BoundContextUser()
                 .Named("IDataContext_BoundContextUser"),
            Component.For<IDataContext>()
                 .ImplementedBy<DataContext>()
                 .LifestyleBoundTo<BoundContextUser2()
                 .Named("IDataContext_BoundContextUser2"),
            Component.For<IDataContext>()
                 .ImplementedBy<DataContext>()
                 .LifestyleTransient(),
            Component.For<BoundContextUser>()
                 .LifestyleTransient(),
            Component.For<BoundContextUser2>()
                 .LifestyleTransient(),
            Component.For<IService>()
                 .ImplementedBy<Service>()
                 .LifeStyleTransient(),
            Component.For<UnboudContextUser>()
                 .LifestyleTransient()
            );

        var bound = container.Resolve<BoundContextUser>();
        var bound2 = container.Resolve<BoundContextUser2>();
        var unbound = container.Resolve<UnboudContextUser>();

        Assert.AreEqual(bound.DataContext, bound.Service.DataContext);
        Assert.AreNotEqual(unbound.DataContext, unbound.Service.DataContext);

        // this fails
        Assert.AreEqual(bound2.DataContext, bound2.Service.DataContext);

        // if bound2.DataContext would not be null, this would fail too
        Assert.AreNotEqual(bound.DataContext, bound2.DataContext);
    }
}

public class BoundContextUser
{
    public IDataContext DataContext { get; set; }
    public IService Service { get; set; }
}

public class BoundContextUser2
{
    public IDataContext DataContext { get; set; }
    public IService Service { get; set; }
}

public interface IService
{
    IDataContext DataContext { get; set; }
}

public class Service : IService
{
    public IDataContext DataContext { get; set; }
}

public class UnboudContextUser
{
    public IDataContext DataContext { get; set; }
    public IService Service { get; set; }        
}

public class DataContext : IDataContext
{

}

public interface IDataContext
{

}
```

**Update**: 
as Marwijn correctly noticed, I've forgot to set lifestyle to Service, so 4 b) isn't actual anymore, but still it does not resolve all properties, as mentioned in 4 a).

Answer (score 1):

First Question 4b:

Since Service is a singleton there will be only 1 in the application. So it will always be true that bound.Service == bound2.service. The first time this service is resolved it is resolved in the context of bound so it will get the Datacontext of bound.
I would consider this a misconfiguration since when bound's lifetime is over, before that of the singleton Service, service will still hold a reference to an object which is from a container point of view no longer alive (Windsor will have called Dispose on it when it implements IDisposable.

With regards to the rest of the questions: You seem to mix up components with classes/interfaces. Each Component.For statement registers 1 component. The first component registered with a certain interface is considered the default component for that interface (unless overriden by IsDefault). When a component is Resolved it will for each dependency try to create/get the default component. If this component can't be resolved (because it's bound to something not in the resolution stack) It will stop.

If you want specify that a component should try to resolve a specific other component you can use DependsOn to specify which component should be resolved. You can see the code below.

Kind regards,
Marwijn.

```
   var container = new WindsorContainer();
    container.Register(
        Component.For<IDataContext>().ImplementedBy<DataContext>(), // default datacontext
        Component.For<IService>().ImplementedBy<Service>(), // default service.

        Component.For<IDataContext>()
             .ImplementedBy<DataContext>()
             .LifestyleBoundTo<BoundContextUser>()
             .Named("IDataContext_BoundContextUser"),                 
        Component.For<IDataContext>()
             .ImplementedBy<DataContext>()
             .LifestyleBoundTo<BoundContextUser2>()
             .Named("IDataContext_BoundContextUser2"),
        Component.For<BoundContextUser>()
             .LifestyleTransient()
             .DependsOn(
                Dependency.OnComponent(typeof(IDataContext),"IDataContext_BoundContextUser"),
                Dependency.OnComponent(typeof(IService), "IService_BoundContextUser")),
        Component.For<BoundContextUser2>()
             .DependsOn(
                Dependency.OnComponent(typeof(IDataContext), "IDataContext_BoundContextUser2"),
                Dependency.OnComponent(typeof(IService), "IService_BoundContextUser2"))
             .LifestyleTransient(),

        Component.For<IService>()
             .ImplementedBy<Service>()
             .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent(typeof(IDataContext),"IDataContext_BoundContextUser"))
             .LifestyleBoundTo<BoundContextUser>()
             .Named("IService_BoundContextUser"),
        Component.For<IService>()
             .ImplementedBy<Service>()
             .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent(typeof(IDataContext), "IDataContext_BoundContextUser2"))
             .LifestyleBoundTo<BoundContextUser2>()
             .Named("IService_BoundContextUser2"),

        Component.For<UnboudContextUser>()
             .LifestyleTransient()
        );

    var bound = container.Resolve<BoundContextUser>();
    var bound2 = container.Resolve<BoundContextUser2>();
    var unbound = container.Resolve<UnboudContextUser>();

    Assert.AreEqual(bound.DataContext, bound.Service.DataContext);
    Assert.AreEqual(unbound.DataContext, unbound.Service.DataContext);
    Assert.AreEqual(bound2.DataContext, bound2.Service.DataContext);
    Assert.AreNotEqual(bound.DataContext, bound2.DataContext);
```

Comment: you're right regarding service misconfiguration, regarding DependsOn - I don't like how it looks as it looks very brittle. In windsor page it states "Bound lifestyle - allows objects to be reused within dependency subtree", so as I understand, I don't need to specify in all levels bound lifestyle, just on top level component and you are specifying how it depends in all levels in your sample.

Comment: It indeed reuses objects in the dependency tree (ie for user and service only one object is created and shared). It does not affect which component get's selected though. I think for a few components it will be managable like this. I would have to think about how to do this with a lot of components. Maybe someone comes up with a better idea. By the way you really not two different classes for BoundContextUser as they seems to be identical ?

Comment: All classes in sample are as short as possible just to indicate the problem, in real project there are much more dependencies. On the other hand, in web projects there may be cases, when you wish to set life style PerWebRequest, but for example in separate thread you won't have access to HttpContext, so PerWebRequest life style won't work.

Comment: As an alternative to naming your dependencies you could implement multiple interfaces which are identical on your components, and register a class  with different but identical interfaces.